# Lazy loading module imports in an __init__.py file python

Tags: python, lazy-loading, import

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for lazy loading imports in an **init** file? I currently have the following folder structure:

```
/mypackage
    __init__.py
    /core
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
        mymodule2.py
```

The **init**.py file in the core folder with the following imports:

```
from mymodule import MyModule
from mymodule2 import MyModule2
```

This way I can just do:

```
from mypackage.core import MyModule, MyModule2
```

However, in the package **init**.py file, I have another import:

```
from core.exc import MyModuleException
```

This has the effect that whenever I import my package in python, MyModule and MyModule2 get imported by default because the core **init**.py file has already been run.

What I want to do, is only import these modules when the following code is run and not before:

```
from mypackage.core import MyModule, MyModule2
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Remember that when python imports it executes the code in the module. The module itself doesn't know how it is imported hence it cannot know whether it has to import `MyModule(2)` or not.

You have to choose: allow `from mypackage.core import A, B` *and* `from core.exc import E` does the non-needed imports (x)**or** do not import `A` and `B` in `core/__init__.py`, hence not allowing `from mypackage.core import A, B`.

Note: Personally I would not import `MyModule(2)` in `core/__init__.py`, but I'd add an `all.py` module that does this, so the user can do `from mypackage.core.all import A, B`
and still have `from mypackage.core.exc import TheException` not loading the unnecessary classes.

(Actually: the `all` module could even modify `mypackage.core` and add the classes to it, so that *following* imports of the kind `from mypackage.core import MyModule, MyModule2` work, but I think this would be quite obscure and should be avoided).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. There are currently a lot of instances of imports using mypackage.core so I don't think I can change that really, but what I've decided to do is to move the exc and common modules out of the core folder.

Answer (score 7):

Unless I'm mistaking your intentions, this is actually possible but requires some magic.

Basically, subclass `types.ModuleType` and override `__getattr__` to import on demand.

Check out the Werkzeug [__init__.py](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/71eab19be2c83fb476de51275e2f9bdf69d5cc10/src/werkzeug/__init__.py) for an example.

Comment: Link to init.py is broken. Can you please fix, or let me know?

Comment: @Uri Here is a fixed (pinned) link: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/c3322bd51fb511fa4be6f208ad048f87d57694d7/src/werkzeug/__init__.py#L181-L209

Answer (score 1):

If your modules structure is like:

```
/mypackage
  __init__.py
  /core
    __init__.py
    MyModule.py
    MyModule2.py
```

or:

```
/mypackage
  __init__.py
  /core
    __init__.py
    /MyModule
      __init__.py
    /MyModule2
      __init__.py
```

then feel free to use

```
from mypackage.core import MyModule, MyModule2
```

without importing them in `__init__.py` under `mypackage/core`

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear, i have a mymodule.py file with a class called MyModule. I want to be able to import MyModule from mypackage.core. Otherwise I'd have to do from mypackage.core.mymodule import MyModule. Hence why I'm importing them in the core folder's __init__.py file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it applies here but in general lazy loading of modules can be done using the [Importing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Importing) package.

Works like this:

```
from peak.util.imports import lazyModule
my_module = lazyModule('my_module')
```

Now my module is only really imported when you use it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You may use follow code in __init__ in module:

```
import apipkg
apipkg.initpkg(__name__, {
    'org': {
        'Class1': "secure._mypkg:Class1",
        'Class2': "secure._mypkg2:Class2",
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question was posted a very long time ago and since then there has been some helpful updates to solve lazy loading submodules.  So for anyone else looking for how to solve this we have great options available now.

Specifically [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/)

Here is an excerpt from that article:

> Another widespread use case for **getattr** would be lazy submodule imports. > Consider a simple example:

```
# lib/__init__.py
import importlib

__all__ = ['submod', ...]

def __getattr__(name):
    if name in __all__:
        return importlib.import_module("." + name, __name__)
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")


# lib/submod.py
print("Submodule loaded")
class HeavyClass:
    ...


# main.py
import lib
lib.submod.HeavyClass  # prints "Submodule loaded"
```