# On-demand imports for huge imports in __all__

Tags: python

I am am making a Python library with the following structure:

```
my_amazing_lib
+--- __init__.py
+--- _core.py
+--- _gui.py
```

In `__init__.py` I have the following:

```
from ._core import core_lib
from ._gui import huge_lib_with_gui

__all__ = ['core_lib', 'huge_lib_with_gui']
```

The goal is to provide an API to users so that they can either use:

1. `from my_amazing_lib import core_lib`
2. or `from my_amazing_lib import huge_lib_with_gui`

depending on their needs.

The problem is that Python automatically imports `huge_lib_with_gui` even if the user only needs `core_lib`, and this can cause various issues: problem with dependencies (gui libs for example), slowdown (eg, `huge_lib_with_gui` spawns multiple threads and background jobs whereas `core_lib` does not need to do that), etc. This issue was already [described here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2014-November/681597.html) (Trap n°2).

Is there a way to **declare a public API** for a **Python module** but **import only the pertinent submodule per user's needs**?

The solution should work for both Python 2.7.10 and Python > 3.3.

Comment: Why not simply `import my_amazing_lib._core.core_lib`?

Comment: I guess you meant `import my_amazing_lib._core.core_lib`. This is ofc possible but does not address the issue: I must drop ```__all__``` which serves as the API descriptor. Either I drop the API, either I accept that all imports are executed and the issues that come with. I am looking for an alternative that could reconcile both (keep the API but no import execution unless required).

Comment: Why do you need the API descriptor? I understand that you don't want to import more than necessary (Trap n°2). But why `__all__`? What is it used for?

Comment: potentially related: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18262696/6084928](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18262696/6084928)

Comment: Because I have lots of submodules, and each submodule has functions and classes that I want to expose publicly, but there are also lots of private functions that should not be exposed.

Comment: @LexScarisbrick Yes a lazy import could be the solution I need.

Comment: @gaborous so prepend name of every private object with an underscore to let you users know that they are private. After that simply stop to care. _We're all consending adults here_, if someone **really** wants to use private something in Python, he will find a way.

Comment: @Rogalski This is not only a matter of scope but also of ergonomics: with ```__all__```, I can make all functions and classes of interest accessible at the top level, like `from my_amazing_lib import core_lib, huge_lib_with_gui`, whereas without it I need to do `import my_amazing_lib._core.core_lib \n import my_amazing_lib._gui._huge_lib_with_gui` and so on and so on... In addition, the discovery of these functionalities is harder. Hence the API. Of course, I also provide documentation, but the philosophy of my lib is to be useable as an easy drop-in solution...

Comment: What kind of objects are `core_lib` and `huge_lib_with_a_gui`? Are they classes that support subclassing, or just things you call (e.g. functions or classes that get instantiated and used, not extended)? If the latter, you could write your own wrapper functions in `__init__.py` that import and run the real functions/classes. I'm not sure there's a good solution for the first case (maybe some kind of metaclass trickery?). In any event, this seems like mostly self-inflicted pain. You can avoid it all by not trying to expose the expensive stuff in the top-level package namespace.

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that they are supposed to be both: they are classes that are usually just called, but they can be also be subclassed (in fact, `huge_lib_with_a_gui` directly inherits from `core_lib` in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping the expensive-to-initialize parts of your library in a separate sub-module, rather than including it directly in the top-level package namespace. While you could use proxy functions to expose the API of the expensive bits in the top level namespace without preemptively importing it all, it's probably more trouble than its worth.

For instance, in your example package layout:

```
my_amazing_lib
+--- __init__.py
+--- _core.py
+--- _gui.py
```

You might want to add a `gui.py` file which imports the public API of `_gui` into a clean namespace.

The contents of `gui.py` would be:

```
from ._gui import huge_lib_with_a_gui

__all__ = ["huge_lib_with_a_gui"]
```

and `__init__.py` file would look like:

```
from ._core import core_lib

__all__ = ["core_lib", "gui"] # don't import gui here, just name it as part of `__all__`
```

Users who need only the core parts of your library can do `from my_amazing_lib import core_lib` and users who need the gui stuff too can add `from my_amazing_lib.gui import huge_lib_with_a_gui`.